# PHP: Writing an if statement for different custom heads

Tags: php, sql, database, if-statement, header

I am creating a database of clients. I am creating error checks in the search function so that it redirects the user back to the search page if the user doesn't exist. I create a header like this:

```
header("Location: search.php?search=not-found");
```

I want to write an `if statement` on the `search.php` page so that if the URL has `"?search=not-found"` at the end, then it displays an error that the user can see by the search box. Such as (I know this isn't correct):

```
if(url contains ['search.php?search=not-found']){
    echo 'That user doesn't exist';
} 
else {
    echo 'Please search for a user';
}
```

How do I write this if statement?

Comment: Can't you just check with `$_GET`? Something like this: `if (isset($_GET['search']) && $_GET['search'] == 'not-found')`. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to get the URL, then use **preg_match** or **strpos** to see if it contains said string, ie not-found

But be aware that that variable isn't entirely secure. So make sure you do some security checks.

```
if((strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"?search=not-found")) === false){
   // Do this
}else{
   // Do this 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`:

```
if($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] == 'search=not-found'){...}
```